# Ошибка бутстрап3 $(...).modal is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь привязать событие для открытия модального окна в бутстрап3:

```
$('#main_footer').on('click',function(){
    $('#load_new_file_ok2').modal('show');
});
```

но при клике на элемент выдает ошибку:

```
$(...).modal is not a function
```

Если привязать с помощью атрибутов, то все работает, но нужно именно js, т.к. кроме этого события я не могу на обработчики show, hide и т.д. ничего повесить. Может не так что подключил - в голову ничего не приходит.

Comment: кусок подключения библиотек js покажите

Comment: Я подключаю через registerCssFile в yii. Я предполагал что каким то образом неправильный порядок подключения файлов, но в инспекторе все правильно.

Comment: а js от бутстрапа?

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

После добавления этой строки все заработало, я так понимаю что  что-то с чем то конфликтовало, как узнать с чем , и в дальнейшем не сталкиваться?

Comment: у вас bootstrap.js подключен раньше чем jquery.js

Comment: Может ли быть такое, что бутстрап подключается раньше потому что загружается со своего сервера, а jquery с внешнего?

Comment: Причина обнаружена. Я ранее сталкивался с подобным, когда подключал 2 файла jquery (второй аджаксом подтягивался), в этот раз я сразу на это и грешил,  но дубликатов не обнаружил. Сейчас случайно заметил, что такое явление только на одной странице, т.к подключен lightBox_plus_query.js !!